# How many regions are created by the set of all hyperplanes defined by a set of points?

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, hyperplane-arrangements

If we have a set of points X in d-dimensional euclidean space, and we look at the set of all hyperplanes that are defined by any subset Y of X (in the sense of being the unique hyperplane containing the points of Y), ranging over all Y in P(X), is there a result for the number of regions defined by this hyperplane arrangement?